# Cannot remove files by prefix

Tags: php

I need to remove certain file by prefix, in particular `featured_image_`, these files are located in a folder:

```
/public_html/myapp/tenants/tenant_ypi/assets/properties/property_600/images/
```

so I did:

```
foreach(glob($property_imgs_path . 'featured_image_') as $filename) {
    unlink($property_imgs_path . $filename);
}
```

essentially `$property_imgs_path` contains the path above and `glob` should get all the files with `featured_image` prefix, the problem is that the `foreach` doesn't start.

What I did wrong?

Comment: Please don't harrass users in the first few minutes.

Comment: I don't believe that you actually need `$property_imgs_path` in your `unlink()` because `$filename` will include the path.